# How to bypass Redis session on Spring Boot application on Redis connection failure?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-session, lettuce

I have implemented Redis session management using LettuceConnectionFactory on my Spring Boot java application by following some of the sample applications out there and the Spring documentation.  It works fine when it can connect to the Redis server.  But the application doesn't respond when the connection fails because it repeatedly trying to connect.  I have done a lot of research to find a solution but couldn't find anything yet. The questions I have are,

1. Is there a way to switch to Spring Session (it could even be a JDBC session) when it can't connect to Redis after certain number of retries?
2. Is there a way to set the number of retries in the connection factory?  I don't see any property for this in spring.redis properties list.

Any help is appreciated.

**Updated on 11/4/2019**

**Application properties:**

---

```java
spring.session.store-type=redis
spring.session.redis.flush-mode=on-save
spring.session.redis.namespace=spring:session
spring.redis.host=*****.windows.net
spring.redis.port=6380
spring.redis.ssl=true
spring.redis.password=****************
spring.redis.timeout=5000ms
spring.redis.custom.command.timeout=1000ms
```

---

**HttpSessionConfig.java:**

---

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpSessionConfig.class);

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String redisHostName;

    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Value("${spring.redis.password}")
    private String redisPassword;

    private @Value("${spring.redis.custom.command.timeout}")
    Duration redisCommandTimeout;

    private @Value("${spring.redis.timeout}")
    Duration socketTimeout;


    @Bean
    LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {

        final SocketOptions socketOptions = SocketOptions.builder().connectTimeout(socketTimeout).build();
    
        final ClientOptions clientOptions = ClientOptions.builder()
                .socketOptions(socketOptions)
                .build();

        LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
                .commandTimeout(redisCommandTimeout)
                .clientOptions(clientOptions)
                .readFrom(ReadFrom.SLAVE_PREFERRED)
                .build();
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration serverConfig = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHostName,
                redisPort);

        final LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(serverConfig,
                clientConfig);
        return lettuceConnectionFactory;
    }


    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> sessionRedisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }     
 
    @Bean
    public ConfigureRedisAction configureRedisAction() {
        return ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP;
    }
}
```

---

**Dependencies:**

---

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>biz.paluch.redis</groupId>
   <artifactId>lettuce</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
   <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
   <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

---

Please let me know if more details are required.

Comment: Could you share a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: @pedrohreis, I have provided more details.  Please take a look and let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

As us we're using 
@Profile(value = "production") for RedisHttpSession and
@Profile(value = "development") for DevSessionConfig

then use can setting spring.profiles.active in application.properties

Comment: How does this answer the question? Apparently OP wants to programmatically switch to a DB session when it is not possible to connect to Redis regardless of the environment.

Comment: pedrohreis is right.  hill123455's response doesn't answer the question.  As it is implemented, the application becomes unresponsive because the connection is attempted continuously.  I need a way to either switch to Spring Session or stop further connection attempts at least for certain amount of time.  Any pointers will be helpful.